# JQuery:Selecting second element in case element with same ID exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it's not a good practice to use same id for different element , but in a case I am forced to use same id for two different elements ( which will be automatically generated in the original program)

I'm trying to select the second element with the same id ( or when scaling say , nth element ).

Is there a way to do this ?

I have created a code snippet here , that shows the problem.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  
  $("#test").css("background","blue");

});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
</div>

<div id="test">
</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: can you use data-id instead? duplicate ids can produce unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Even if i use `data-id` , what if it has same value ? Will the selection return an array ?

Comment: yes, see below answer with demo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must not have duplicate ids but if you can not do that you can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [:eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). The `:eq` takes the index of element of the collection. You may also want to use background-color.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/luxesolola/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
 $("[id=test]:eq(1)").css("background-color","blue");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the data-id attribute instead since duplicate ids can produce unpredictable behaviour.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){      
  $("[data-id='test']:eq(1)").css("background","blue");
});
```

```css
[data-id='test'] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-id="test">
</div>

<div data-id="test">
</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I'm looking to select the second one alone , not every element. That is where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test:eq(1)").css("background-color","blue");
```

Comment: I now get it, i should have written it like this $("#text:eq(1)").css("background-color","blue");